# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server timeout

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing an application which crawl html from 2 websites (website A and website B) using Selenium Chromedriver. It works well when I test on local, but when I deploy to server, timeout error that I can't understand.
When deployed to live enviroment, the application works fine with A, but not B. I get an error like this:
`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:5555/session/da9eb470832c1d5f74346e548233ccc0/url timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out`

I tried to use `--no-sandbox` and extend timeout but it doesn't work. I tried to access other websites like google.com, A,... it works fine.

I wonder if there is something wrong in my firewall config goes wrong so my application can't access to a specific website. Which port selenium use to send request to outside?

Please help me if you have any opinion. Thanks a lot